# DB Query Inside A Method

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this method here to fetch an user name, and right at the beginning I have some global variables definitions to retrieve the db connection info I'm making:

```
global $dbprefix;
global $servername;
global $username;
global $password;
```

Which are referring to these variables in a file I've added with `require_once`. If I call this method from within the same file, it does display what I'm looking for (an user name), however, if I call this method from another file (even after creating an object and such), I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user **''@'localhost'** (using password: NO) in /var/www/html/dotproject-dev/modules/reports/reports.custom.class.php on line 28
Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Observe that it seems that the database, user and password variables are empty. My question is, where is it looking for these values? Is it in the class file or in my viewer itself? I've also tried setting these variables in the viewer file just for testing purposes and I get the same results.

Comment: share your db connection code ?

Comment: @Rishi $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
  
  if ($db->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  }

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this, the only I could make it work was to pass those values ($dbprefix, $password, etc) as method parameters. Then I just added the dbconfig file (require_once) in my viewer.